# jquery auto resizable set of divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a fixed-sized `wrapper` div somewhere in my page. I want to dynamically add child `div`s to it, but i want all the child divs to maintain equal size.

Does anybody know any plugin for that?

**EDIT**

I want the divs to be only added in horizontal direction. Its a 1xN grid. (thanks for the comment.)

Comment: This is too general. Do you want them stacked vertically? Do you want a modular grid with equal sized boxes? What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to add divs to a wrapper div and fix their size:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix"></div>

<input type="button" id="AddDiv" value="AddDiv" />
```

**CSS**

```css
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; 
    display: table; 
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

#wrapper {

}
#wrapper > div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: #cc0000;
    float: left;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#AddDiv').on('click', function () {
    $('#wrapper').append($('<div />'));
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UBE7m/)**